# Firebase Crashlytics for Ionic v3

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic3, crashlytics

I am trying to implement crashlytics for my Ionic project. Since the crashlytics is being migrated to firebase from fabrics and firebase's own crash-report is slowly deprecating, am planning to implement crashlytics in my Ionic application. But there is no proper documentation to do so. Can anyone help me on this?

1st Approach:

When I tried the approach given in [Cordova-plugin for crashlytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-crashlytics) am unable to add the plugin to my app and the FirebaseCrashlytics.initialise() is undefined.

2nd Approach:

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin --variable FABRIC_API_KEY=XXX --variable FABRIC_API_SECRET=xxx

When I tried to add the fabric native plugin am unable to get the API key and Build secret from the fabric site. The site is totally collapsed and am unable to add new project.

Comment: Same problem hier, have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Zakaria.dem no. Hope firebase will migarate the crashlytics soon